# Capturing conditional output with Expect or Shell

Tags: shell, expect

I have been trying to write an expect script which would capture the output from a remote device only under some conditions . Alternately if it could capture the output to a certain file under normal conditions and to another file under failure conditions that too would work out for me .

The devices in question here are mostly Routers and Switches and in some cases modems .

For instance I would want to capture output to file "Fail_OSPF.txt" in case the OSPF neighborship is down , 2-way or attempt on an interface . In case OSPF neighborship is Full then go ahead and capture the same output to a file "Good_OSPF.txt"

I have looked at the possibilities of the if/else statements in expect but in my case the output would be complex and would need to analysed before firing the else condition

A few examples would be greatly appreciated .

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: What you need to do is perfectly possible with Tcl/Expect. As @glennjackman said, post what you got as a starter, and we can get the ball rolling from there. In addition to your first shot at the code, sample outputs of the command(s) you will be using would be useful.

Comment: Hi Glenn/James , What I am doing now is invoking the Expect script with a shell script , capturing whatever output possible and then doing the editing of the output files with SED . This seems to work for me . Any better suggestions.